# C no EOF signal

Tags: c, mingw, atom-editor, eof

I am trying make a program that counts the number of characters that are entered, but the there seems to be a problem with the EOF signal, because the program does not end after I press enter.  I do not want to use a flag to terminate it manually.

I have tried using CTRL+Z and CTRL+X , CTRL+D , or entering -1, and none of that worked.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
  double count;
    for(count=0; (getchar())!=EOF; ++count)
    {
          ;
    }
    printf("Char Count%.0f\n",count);

}
```

I'm using Windows 10, with Atom editor, with the gpp-compiler (3.0.7) package (by kriscross07), and minGW 8.2.0.

Comment: ctrl-c on windows

Comment: @ryyker ctrl-c doesn't send the break signal ?

Comment: @bruno - The program, exactly as written, broke with ctrl-c on WIndows.

Comment: @ryyker so this is not what the OP wants

Comment: Out of that why do you use a _double_ to count rather than an _int_ (or _unsigned int_) ?

Comment: @ryyker ctrl-c is an interrupt. It ends whatever the terminal is doing.  It's not EOF. EOF is ctrl-d in Linux and Mac. And in Windows ctrl-z.

Answer (score 1):

It works very well if you run the program from command prompt - but it will not work if you start the program via the IDE.

```
int main()
{
    int c;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        printf("Char %d read\n", c);
    }
    printf("Exiting .... \n");
    return 0;
}
```

[image]